# Unable to find the SharePoint 2010 Server SP1 Download link

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, service-pack

I tried every where and i am unable to find the SharePoint 2010 SP1 download link.

Will installing SharePoint 2010 Server Sp2 installs SP1 as well?

Comment: you are looking only SP1 or complete SharePoint 2010 bits with SP1?

Comment: Complete bits of SP1.  basically, I want to take my farm version to march 2015 CU. For which I need to install SP1 and SP2 before March 2015 CU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 SP1 is gone, now you will get only SharePoint 2010 SP2 (which include all the previous updates). You can install the March CU after that.

I checked from MSDN and they have only SharePoint 2010 SP2 only.